# How to use single head tag for all pages of a web site

Tags: javascript, html, header, each, head

What should I do to make the same link tags reachable on each page without being written in their head tags over and over again?

Here is the jQuery snippet that I use to reach 'header' tag everywhere but It doesn't work for the 'head' tag the same way.

```
<script>
    $.get('header.html', function (response) {
        $('#header').html(response);
    });
</script>
<header id="header"></header>
```

Comment: Configure your backend to serve it in a DRY fashion instead, ideally. A template engine might help.

Comment: just for sanity check, place the element above the script that tries to populate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this.

```js
let headLinks = `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="two.css" />
   `;

  document.querySelector('#html-head').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headLinks);
```

```html
<head id="html-head">
    ...meta contents...
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
$("#someDivID").load("b.html",function(data){
    var value=$(data).find("#elementID").attr("attributeName");
});
```